# <Entry.Behaviors> doesn't work inside ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: listview, datatemplate, eventtocommand

I'm using an Entry view inside of a ListView's ItemTemplate, and I want to bind a Command to the Completed event of the Entry view (ala MVVM).
The top of the XAML with the DataTemplate definition looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MedLemnMobile.Models"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MedLemnMobile.ViewModels"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="MedLemnMobile.Views.EquationLibPage"
             Title="EquationSets"
             Focused="ContentPage_Focused"
             x:FieldModifier="public"
             x:Name="myEqLibPage"
             AutomationId="myEqLibPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
             x:DataType="viewModel:EquationLibViewModel">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:EquationLibViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myEqSetDataTemplateViewCell_1">
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View Background="Goldenrod">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Entry x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="myEquationSetNameEntry"
                               x:DataType="models:EquationSet"
                               Text="{Binding EquationSetName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               TextColor="{DynamicResource TextForegroundColor}">
                            <Entry.Behaviors>
                                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    x:DataType="viewModel:EquationLibViewModel"
                                    EventName="Completed"
                                    Command="{Binding EquationSetNameCompletedCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{x:Reference myEqLibPage}"/>
                            </Entry.Behaviors>
                        </Entry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Later in the XAML, the ListView definition looks like so:

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView   x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="myEquationSetsListView"
                        AutomationId="myEquationSetsListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding EquationLib}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myEqSetDataTemplateViewCell_1}">
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

And, the Command declaration in the ViewModel looks like so:

```
namespace MedLemnMobile.ViewModels
{
    public class EquationLibViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand GotoMenuCommand { get; }
        public ICommand GotoParamsCommand { get; }
        public ICommand EquationSetNameCompletedCommand { get; }

        public EquationLibViewModel()
        {
            GotoMenuCommand = new Command<EquationLibPage>(GotoMenu);
            GotoParamsCommand = new Command<EquationLibPage>(GotoParams);
            EquationSetNameCompletedCommand = new Command<EquationLibPage>(EquationSetNameCompleted);
        }
```

I expect that when the user "Completes" entering the value in the Entry view, that the Command EquationSetNameCompletedCommand will fire.
I have set a breakpoint at the beginning of the Command's code, and the breakpoint is never triggered.
Any help figuring out why this Command is not firing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work! The answer was in the Command Binding as follows:

```
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                            x:DataType="viewModel:EquationLibViewModel"
                            EventName="Completed"
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EquationSetNameCompletedCommand,
                                      Source={Reference myEqLibPage}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Reference myEqLibPage}"/>
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
```